# Access to modules using asp.net core identity

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a project with modules like Project, Task, Lead, etc etc. I need a setting where I can set/revoke permissions to access these modules, to a user. I need to know whether I should create Roles corresponding to all the modules that I have and assign them. Or is there a better alternative approach for this?

Comment: You have now implemented role-based authorization, if this does not meet your needs, you may consider using claim-based and policy-based authorization.

Comment: Or you can provide more detailed content so that we can clearly understand the situation you are encountering now.

Comment: What are you talking about when you say "modules"? Maybe you can turn this question into a wiki.